# Periodically run a method of an instantiated object

Tags: c#, multithreading

If have an object that looks like this:

```
public class MyTask
{
    private Connection _someKindOfConnectionThatShouldStayOpen;

    public MyTask() { ... Opens connection and other stuff } 

    void DoWork(object arg) { ... }
}
```

I want to create a small application that creates the object and run the DoWork method periodically (say every second), without destroying the object.
What is the best way of doing this? (ie. safest and best practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx).  The timer's callback can call DoWork.

Have the Timer be a private field of your object.  Instantiate and start it when the object is instantiated.

Implement IDisposable for your object and be sure you dispose the timer when you dispose of your object.

Comment: Ok, I was looking at this, but was not sure it was the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

In your application, create a class-level instance of MyTask and a timer. In the timer's elapsed event, call the method you want. I would do something similar to this:

```
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static MyTask taskInstance = new MyTask();  
    static ManualResetEventSlim cancelEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

    static void Main()
    {       
        var timer =  new Timer
        {
            AutoReset = true,
            Interval = 1000
        };
        timer.Elapsed += (x, y) => taskInstance.DoWork();
        cancelEvent.Wait();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this is not complete or tested, but it's the basic idea I'd go for. Whenever you need to stop your application (due to user input or whatever), call cancelEvent.Set();